# How to SSH to my Ubuntu 20.04 machine on VMware from the Windows PC it's installed on?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vmware

I've tried everything I can, but I keep getting `Connection refused`.
I have VMware Workstation 16 Player, and Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS installed on it.

I installed `openssh-server` and created key-pair using the keygen. I copied the private key to my Windows host and converted it to PPK using PuTTYgen.
I then enabled port forwarding (ports 22, 2222) on my router.

But I still get connection refused when I try to SSH from the Windows host to the VMware using my ISP public IP - I want the public IP because if it works, I want to SSH from another network.

I tried to SSH using 3 options: Windows 10 command line, PuTTY and FileZilla - all of them refused.

What are the steps I can do to see what's causing it? I already read multiple articles to try and debug this, but everything seems to be right. I can clean install Ubuntu and follow the steps you tell me. I just can't get it to work

Thanks

Comment: How is your virtual machine networked?,   I it private, NAT or bridged?
What is the IP address of your Windows box and your Virtual machine?
You can test the sshd is working by ssh localhost from your virtual machines console.

Comment: Check if the port forwarding really works, and scan your public IP with some port scanner, for opened ports.

Comment: SSH from inside the virtual machine using ssh localhost works. The network is NAT (I saw in VMware settings). How can I check if the port forwarding really works? Also, could it be something about config files? I didn't touch anything there besides editing sshd_config and uncommenting `#port 22`

Comment: In order to connect using your internet IP address, you need to have public IP address purchased from your ISP. To scan your IP for opened ports you might try this:https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap